# Carrierwave Uploads stopped working in model with Awesome Nested Set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage, carrierwave, rails-admin, awesome-nested-set

In my Rails 4.2 app, the file uploads stopped working for the model which has following

```
acts_as_nested_set counter_cache: :children_count, touch: true
```

Removing this line, the uploads starts working again.
I'm managinh content via RailsAdmin using Carrierwave and fog-google gems. File uploads for other models are working fine which uses the same uploader. I can update or create record fine but the image is not being uploaded. It fails without any error.

Answer (score 1):

Moving `acts_as_nested_set counter_cache: :children_count, touch: true` after setting uploader in model solved this issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! I was able to find this only after I figured it out myself :( There go 2 hours...

Comment: Also for anyone interested in learning more, feel free to check out the issue: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/2174